# The name xxx DataProvider does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, data-binding

I am not so familiar with xaml. Can somebody help me. Why does "The name MercerCataloDataProvider does not exist in the namespace". As far as I can see, is everything in the same namespace and should be available? What can I do?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace WPFOnboarding01
{
    public class MercerCatalogDataProvider
    {
        private MainDataSetTableAdapters.MercerJobCatalogTblTableAdapter adapter;

        private MainDataSet dataSet;

        public MercerCatalogDataProvider()
        {
            dataSet = new MainDataSet();
            adapter = new MainDataSetTableAdapters.MercerJobCatalogTblTableAdapter();
            adapter.Fill(dataSet.MercerJobCatalogTbl);
        }

        public DataView GetMercerCatalog()
        {
            return dataSet.MercerJobCatalogTbl.DefaultView;
        }
    }
}
```

> Blockquote

```
    <Window x:Class="WPFOnboarding01.TestBinding"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WPFOnboarding01"

        xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="TestBinding" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Window.Resources>
        <!-- create an instance of our DataProvider class -->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MercerCatalogDataProvider"

            ObjectType="{x:Type local:MercerCatalogDataProvider}"/>
        <!-- define the method which is invoked to obtain our data -->
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MercerJobCatalog"

          ObjectInstance="{StaticResource MercerCatalogDataProvider}"

          MethodName="GetMercerCatalog"/>

    </Window.Resources>
```

[Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LE603.png)

Comment: Try to ignore it and click `F5`, does it run? XAML designer often bugs. Or it's legimately not yet build with this change project.

Comment: Try change x:Key="MercerCatalogDataProvider" to other key name.

Comment: Project builds but, the designer view does not work.

Comment: X:key Change did not help

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: @Tronald Professional 2017, V 15.9.15

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this could be of help. But whenever I have this issue I do the following. 
1. Disable project code and rebuild
[image]

2. If step 1 doesn't work, Close VS. Delete all obj, bin folders from the project. Open and rebuild the project. It should work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,  we should know the following format:

```
 <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MercerCatalog" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MercerCatalogDataProvider}" MethodName="GetMercerCatalog" />
```

**Key** - Set the Key property to CarData.

**ObjectType** - The data provider will instantiate an object based on the ObjectType property.

**MethodName** - The data provider will call this method after instantiating the object.

**For my experience, when I define the class and use it, it will show this error. You can rebuild your application to solve this issue.**

You can refer the following sample (Visual Studio 2019 16.2.3):

XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <ObjectDataProvider x:Key="MercerCatalog" ObjectType="{x:Type local:MercerCatalogDataProvider}" MethodName="GetMercerCatalog" />  
    </Window.Resources>
     <Grid>
        <DataGrid Grid.Row="0" CanUserAddRows="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource MercerCatalog}}"  >    
      </DataGrid>
    </Grid>



 public class MercerCatalogDataProvider
    {
        public ObservableCollection<User> ListItems { get; set; }
        public MercerCatalogDataProvider()
        {
            ListItems = new ObservableCollection<User>
            {

              new User { Name = "Item1"},
              new User { Name = "Item2"},
              new User { Name = "Item3"},
              new User { Name = "Item4"}
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<User> GetMercerCatalog()
        {
            return ListItems;
        }
    }
    public class User
    {
        public bool Add { get; set; } = false;  
        public string Name { get; set; }

    }
```

[image]

Comment: Very good explanation, thank you. Unfortunately it still does not work.

Comment: I could partly solve the issue. I created a new project. Added a new Window and created the class "DataProvider". Then re-builded the project and added the binding in XAML.

Luckily I am not so far in my project and can handle to take over the stuff into a new project. Even then, I am wondering how can this be, in a professional software like Visual Studio. Any alternatives for WPF?